# request header personalizado Javascript , "Provisional headers are shown"

Tags: javascript, cors, headers

Buen día, estoy tratando de mandar datos a través de un *header personalizado*, mi problema esta cuando el explorador no realiza la petición, estoy seguro que es por temas de seguridad, pero he visto en otras paginas que si se puede mandar.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?.

Estos son los headers personalizados

```
headers : {
    'authSurfer':'5',
    'perfil':'3'
} ,
```

Agradezco el apoyo.

Mi código JS:

```js
$("#uploadForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'miURL',
            headers : {
            'authSurfer':'5',
                'perfil':'3'
            } ,
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#uploadStatus').html('<img src="images/uploading.gif"/>');
            },
            error:function(){
                $('#uploadStatus').html('<span style="color:#EA4335;">Images upload failed, please try again.<span>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
                $('#uploadStatus').html('<span style="color:#28A74B;">Images uploaded successfully.<span>');
                $('.gallery').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>INICIO</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
     <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Choose Images</label>
        <input type="file" name="images[]" id="fileInput" multiple >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
    </form>
    <!-- Display upload status -->
    <div id="uploadStatus"></div>    
    </div>

    <script src="/assets/js/upLoadFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: que no  realiza la petición y el explorador me arroja “Provisional headers are shown”

Comment: Generalmente, si no hay más mensajes de error, eso es debido a alguna extensión de tu navegador que bloquea la petición